# How to create numpy array of other numpy arrays with iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to make a numpy array where each element is a (48,48) shape numpy array, essentially making a big list where I can iterate over and retrieve a different 48x48 array each time.

```
for i in range(1):
    new_image = np.fromstring(train_np[i][1],dtype=int,sep=" ")
    new_image = new_image.reshape(48,48) #create the new 48x48 correctly

    image_train = np.stack([image_train,new_image]) #this line only works once
```

When range is 1 (running only once), stack returns the expected result shape of (2, 48 48). Running more than once though, yields

```
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

Is there a better operation to use than np.stack for this case? I would like to iterate over and see the shape become (2,48,48) -> (3,48,48) -> (4,48,48) ... and so on.

Comment: Why not just preallocate a big array and fill part of it each loop? Or if you *must* use `np.stack`, then it's probably way faster to append all your arrays to a regular python list, then join them all together in the end.

Comment: There's `np.concatenate` which allows you to specify the axis to concatenate along, but again, it's probably way faster to just preallocate.

Comment: `np.stack` joins a list of identically shaped arrays along a new axis. It's not meant to be used iteratively. None of the `concatenate/stack` family should be used iteratively.  Pay close attention to dimensions when using these.

Comment: It sounds like you need a list of numpy arrays, not a numpy array of numpy arrays. Can you clarify things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy` is optimized for large, parallel calculations.  It doesn't have very flexible data shapes by design, so if you can't hardcode the shape of your data, you're usually better off using lists (which are flexible) and then calling `numpy` at the end to stack them.

```
image_train = []

for i in range(1):
    new_image = np.fromstring(train_np[i][1],dtype=int,sep=" ")
    new_image = new_image.reshape(48,48) 
    image_train.append(new_image) 

image_train = np.stack(image_train)
```

That said, you *could* use `np.concatenate` for this, but it would be dreadfully slow and poor practice.

Comment: This ended up being much faster than concatenate and got me the shape I need. Thanks!